# the trait `anchor_lang::AccountDeserialize` is not implemented for `anchor_spl::token::Mint`

Tags: rust, smartcontracts, solana, solana-web3js, anchor-solana

I am trying to CPI the Token Program to send spl-tokens to a wallet. For this the derive accounts in the context struct has three accounts without any attribute over them:

1. mint_token_out: Account<'info, Mint> (which is the mint address)
2. token_out: Account<'info, TokenAccount>(which is the token account that the token would be sent out from) and
3. token_program: Program<'info, Token>.

But I get four Trait not implemented errors. They are:

1. the trait `AccountSerialize` is not implemented for `anchor_spl::token::Mint` at line --- mint_token_out
2. the trait `anchor_lang::AccountDeserialize` is not implemented for `TokenAccount` at line --- token_out: Account<'info, TokenAccount>
3. the trait `anchor_lang::Owner` is not implemented for `TokenAccount` at line --- token_out: Account<'info, TokenAccount>
4. the trait `anchor_lang::Owner` is not implemented for `anchor_spl::token::Mint` at line --- mint_token_out: Account<'info, Mint>

Is there something wrong I'm doing?

I have tried adding the constraint #[account(mut, has_one = wallet, owner = wallet)] as the account attribute for mint_token_out. But I still get the error..

Comment: Did you put #[derive(Accounts)] on the context struct ?

Answer (score 1):

That error indicates that you did not use `#[derive(Accounts)]` for the related struct that you created for the method.

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct YourTructForContext<'info>{}
```

`#[derive(Accounts)]` Implements an Accounts deserializer on the given struct. Meaning it allows this struct to process user addresses and accounts.